# How to write an echo consisting of static and dynamic elements

Tags: php

I need to call `<li>` classes dynamically like this :

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); echo $filters; ?> data-expand="-100">
```

My structure is :

```
echo '<li> <h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
```

How can I implement the above structure in my structure ?

I need to fill `<li>` class dynamically from the function `post_class($classes)` with filters and data expand.

The help which i am seeking is how to write the 'echo' so that it shows the static elements like li element and data-expand and in the same time execute the dynamic elements like the function `post_class($classes)` and variable '$filters' and '$term->name' and gives me output like this

```
<li class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 post-3946 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail jsn-master first instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" data-expand="-100" >
```

The function will return the li classes. 
Please help.

Comment: You should change `post_class()` so it returns a string instead of doing its own printing. Then you can concatenate it in an `echo` statement.

Comment: `<li <?php post_class( $classes , array("class" => $filters)); ?> data-expand="-100">` You can add the classes like that :)

Comment: I am getting error when i echo your code. How can i write your code inside echo ?

Comment: Show your `post_class`method and value for `$classes` and `$classes . So you can get help for your question